# Project template: file's replacement with TargetFileName

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2013, vsix

I'm trying to make a Template where the Project's name user provide on "Add-New project" will affect file name. As discribed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa(v=vs.120).aspx), this should be rather easy. But nothing I do in vstemplate file won't modify the file name, as I thought it should.

vstemplate relevant section:

```
<Project File="ProjectTemplate.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">AssemblyInfo.cs</ProjectItem>
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$Class1.cs" OpenInEditor="true">Class1.cs</ProjectItem>
</Project>
```

I would expect that after vsix (which referencing the C# project template) installed, and when adding new project with the newly created template, the creation is failed with this error:[image]

I also tried to modify only the `csproj` file, but that was unsuccessful too: it did create a project, but the desired replacement wasn't executed.

Does file renaming with vstemplate is doable??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `csproj`-File you are referencing in the `Project` node in your `vstemplate`-File needs to be an **extra file**, not the `csproj`-File referenced in your template project' solution.

Also add a reference to $safeprojectname$Class1.cs to the extra `csproj`-File.
Then it should work as expected.

So the file structure in your template project would be for example:

```
/
-- /Properties
          -- AssemblyInfo.cs
-- Project.csproj               [The one referenced in your .sln]
-- ProjectTemplate.csproj       [The one used for replacements]
-- Class1.cs
```